# What is causing these dents on the model/is it fixable?

Tags: mesh, objects, shaders, artifacts

I downloaded a free to use car model and I noticed some parts have these artifacts:
[image]

I applied scale, recalculated normals, tried with shade flat/smooth/auto smooth but I can't seem to fix them. Is there any workaround to fix such artifacts?

Here is a file of the problematic mesh:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c-VF1QCZj4ZcefKoeov3NPhhV0DIAsJA/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Not easy to understand the artefact you're talking about, maybe try to go in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: Sorry face orientation makes it barely visible :/

But clearing split normals fixed it! You rule moonboots :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you have bad split normals (these are the normals that determine the shading), to fix that go in the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*